# [JAVA]: How to insert and retrieve Dynamic JSON in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am developing JAX-RS web service with MongoDB in backend. I am using Morphia for Class to Mongo Collection Mapping. In one of the insert operation we have a Json inside a JSON.

```
{
    "deviceId" : "57b5afc7e91c14ce01425fb6",
    "data":{
        "mah":50,
        "volt":23
    },
    "isSynced" : true
}
```

In this the JSON with key "data" is dynamic. which can be anything.

How should I insert a dynamic JSON inside collection? As it is dynamic I cannot map it to a class.

Comment: encode the data value to string for storage, which you'll have to decode to json object when retrieving.

Comment: @Tschallacka Thanks for the update but is there any datatype in MongoDB or Morphia to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could store that JSON as a `Map` inside your entity.  The generics might get funky, though, since the value type would likely have to be `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I used **com.mongodb.BasicDBObject** for this. This has in-built constructor which serves the purpose.

Comment: How did you use BasicDBObject? I tried it by creating an empty one and stuffing name/value pairs into it. When I save it to Morphia, the document contains only Class metadata, but none of the actual data.

Comment: @Keenan can you post your code snippet so that I can check.